# Increase top border height WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, height, border

How to increase top border height on WinForms, i use Sizable FormBorderStyle.
[image: Example]

Comment: You can't, as far as I know. You'd have to disable the border entirely and draw it yourself.

Comment: Stop upvoting that comment, it *is* possible, at least with Aero Glass enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work when Aero is off, but you can try `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`.

See this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx